# Textract on Python 3 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textract.parsers.pdf_parser'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3 on Windows 10. I am using Textract to extract data from pages from PDF. I am able to fetch the data when I run the tool using the editor. But I am getting the following error when I create an EXE using Pyinstaller.

The following are the libraries I've used for extract.

```
import textract
```

Following is the code that runs fine in the editor but not in the EXE.

```
text = textract.process(outputpdf1, method='tesseract', language='eng')
```

outputpdf1 is a one page PDF.

Following is the error I am getting.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textract\parsers\__init__.py", line 69, in process
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textract.parsers.pdf_parser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "PDF_Splitter.py", line 383, in UploadAction2
  File "PDF_Splitter.py", line 120, in splitPDF
  File "textract\parsers\__init__.py", line 72, in process
  File "textract\exceptions.py", line 21, in __init__
  File "textract\parsers\__init__.py", line 89, in _get_available_extensions
  File "c:\users\V\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\re.py", line 234, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "c:\users\V\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "c:\users\V\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "c:\users\V\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "c:\users\V\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "c:\users\V\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 507, in _parse
    code = _escape(source, this, state)
  File "c:\users\V\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 369, in _escape
    raise source.error("incomplete escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
re.error: incomplete escape \U at position 2
```

Is there anything I am missing: Including any library, installing any other software.?